# React GitHub Repo API

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, axios

I'm working on something that allows users to type in a username and display all the github repos for that user in a separate react component inside a repolist component.

I can get the JSON data for all the repos but I can't iterate through the object to display a card for each repo, I don't know how to reference the data nested inside the object.

I should note that testData was originally filled with test data that I could only get working as a single dimensional array, rather than an object.

App.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { CardList } from './Components/CardList.js';
    import { testData } from './Components/Card.js'
    import { Form } from './Components/Form.js'; 
    import './App.css';

    class App extends React.Component {

      state = {
        profiles: testData,
      };
      addNewSearch = (searchData) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          profiles: [...prevState.profiles, searchData],
        }))
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
            <div>{this.props.title}</div>
              <div className=" search-box" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <Form onSubmit={this.addNewSearch}/>
              </div>
              <div className="bgbox rounded">

                <div className="cardbox">
                  <CardList profiles={this.state.profiles} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </header>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App
```

Form.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

    export class Form extends React.Component {
        state = { userName: '' };
        handleSubmit = async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const resp = await
            axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.userName}/repos?per_page=250`)
            this.props.onSubmit(
                resp.data
            );

        };
        render() {
            return (
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="btn-group">
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.userName} className="form-control" placeholder="GitHub User" onChange={event => this.setState({userName: event.target.value })}></input>
                        <button className="btn btn-dark">Go!</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            )
        }
    }
```

Card.js

```
    import React from 'react';

    export const testData = [];


    export class Card extends React.Component {
        render() {
            const repo = this.props;
            return (
                <div className="card border-secondary mb-3" style={{ width: '20rem', fontSize: '12px'}}>
                    <h5 className="card-header">{repo.name}</h5>
                    <div className="card-body text-secondary">
                        <p className="card-text">{repo.name}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

CardList.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Card } from './Card.js'

    export const CardList = (props) => (
        <div>
            {props.profiles.map(profile => <Card key={profile.id} {...profile} />)}
        </div>
    );
```

Edit: screenshot of what it currently looks like
[image: image of card rendered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to see that is the result from the request you are making.

```
[
  {
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "bla-bla-repo",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

On each request you get an array of repos of a user.

You are storing a all repos of some user, so you have an array of user's repos. (Array of array)

When doing `profiles.map(profile => ...)`, `profile` is an array of repos. You can't access `profile.id`.

What you can do a `.map` inside another `.map`.

```
{props.profiles.map(profile => profile.map(repo => <Card key={repo.id} repo={repo} />))}
```

This will List all repos of all users.

---

If this isn't what you want to do, and you want to display all the repos of only one user, you need to pass to `CardList`, only one profile.

```
<CardList profiles={this.state.profiles[indexOfTheProfileYouWantToDisplay]} />
```

Comment: Hi, this is perfect. i added your last line to my App.js and change it so that it would only render one cardlist. I added one line of dummy data so it would have something to display or it would error. When i searched for a username it replaced the dummy data with the list of repos! May I ask, do you know how to stop it from throwing an error when there is no [0] in the array?

Comment: @HollowA you should do some checking like `this.state.profiles && this.state.profiles[0]`, because `profiles` can be `null` or `undefined`. You should do this checking every time you use `.map`, also doing it in `{props.profiles && props.profiles.map(...)`